# What is the difference between in depth and in-depth?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-difference, hyphens

It seems that in depth is like two separate words like

> I have studied this subject in some depth.

But in-depth is like one word and an adjective

> He has an in-depth knowledge of the subject .

Am I correct? Would you provide more information about their difference?

Answer (score 6):

"In-depth" is an adjective which means comprehensive and precise, while "in depth" is a phrase or idiom which works like an adverb, meaning the same, so as comprehensively and precisely. Examples: 
An in-depth analysis of the problem. 
The problem was analysed in depth.

Comment: Can you say `[he did x] more in depth`, or would you have to say `[he did x] in more depth`?